# How to Keep listening from socket even app get closed iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, tcp, udp

I want to communicate with a embebed device though `TCP/IP`, done with communication part. I used `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` to communicate, all goes well when the app is in the foreground, but I want to do some communication even when the app is closed. I have had success with sending data to device after app get closed for that I used `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0)`  on  `applicationDidEnterBackground` event to keep pushing data after app is closed. I want to listen to a port even if the app gets closed.
I setup a port to listen for that I write the delegate method in app `AppDelegate.m`.

```
- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
  fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext
```

To listen a port but it never gets called, what is missing? Is it possible to listen a port after app get closed?

Comment: You are not allowed to do this.  Your app will be terminated after 10 minutes if it tries.

Comment: yes , app's background code execution stops after 10 min , what will be the solution for this or have to create voip application for this ?

Comment: You can't run this kind of stuff in the background.  Apple doesn't want your app sucking away at the battery, because they know that the average user will not understand that it is your app doing it and will think "iPhones have bad battery life."  So unless it is critical to the performance of your app (i.e. falls into one of the approved background categories), you can't do it.  End of story.  There is no solution except to limit your app to jailbroken devices that are patched to disable this watchdog.